# Should I store frequently running/needed query results to the Session scope in Coldfusion?

Tags: mysql, session, coldfusion, scope, storage

I have a system running `Coldfusion8/MySQL 5.0.88`.

On some pages I need to pre-query parameters based on (logged in) users. For example, the site has a product search, which only allows to search products from sellers that authorized the user (`allow-list`).

Right now, when the user goes to the products page, I'm building the `allow-list` to display sellers. When the user triggers a product search, I invoke a search.cfc, which again builds the `allow-list` to perform the search. On another page, the user can lock/unlock sellers, so the list may change regularly.

**Question:**
Should I store the `allow-list` to the Session to have it available everywhere and not have to requery the database all the time? The list can be quite long (13-digit ID, comma separated). WOuld I need a *Session.rebuild = true/false* parameter to indicate, when to rebuild and not take the current Session value (after updating). Also will query caching make any sense if the query is identical, but on separate pages?

Thanks for some thoughts.

Comment: the query `cachedwithin` is based on a number of properties of the cfquery tag. It's possible that you'll end up with more than copy in the cache if you have more than one cfquery getting the results. (I would assume your cfquery is in a single function in the CFC, so it shouldn't be an issue.)  As for the authorization issue, that may still be protected values.  What will the sellers say if someone makes a purchase from them 5 minutes after that person was disallowed from buying from that seller?

Comment: Good point. I just ran through my user_cfc and set a Session.rebuild_user flag to all functions that alter the underlying table and `allow-list`. Haven't tesed, but buyer-wise I think this is ok. Seller-wise I'm not sure yet, because the seller frequently update their allowed-list and I don't know if how to catch this if the buyer is logged in. Any idea?

Comment: we are talking edge case here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the values stored in the session are not the security that protects them, that's fine.

Query caching is based on the query being sent to the server, if it is identical it should not even touch the db, but get it from memory, effectively doing what your suggesting.

Comment: No, it's not the protection values, it's the resulting from checking for authorization (id 1 is ok, id 2 is ok...). Regarding caching, you are saying it does not matter if the query name="abc" is on page 1 and page 2. First time it is cached, it will be read from the cache on every page? I still need to figure out how to re-cache once the user changes something though

Answer (score 2):

Choosing where to save the cache depends a lot on what you expect your system to do.

You don't want to cache the data for longer than is useful, so putting it in the Session scope is good because it will only be cached for as long as the user is active.  Additionally, if sellers don't care if a buyer manages to buy something from then even if they've been recently removed, then you never need to update the cache, just wait for it to expire.

Alternately you can rely on ColdFusion's built in query cache.  You can supply a timeframe that you expect most users to be active on the site and you can easily update the cache with a small bit of code.  A possible disadvantage, or advantage, depending on your point of view is that there is a fixed number of cached queries on the server which will flush your cache for you if the number of cached queries is exceeded.  This provides some level of memory management at the expense of possibly refetching queries that you would prefer stayed cached.

Here is one way to handle the query cache.  This will cache the query until the timespan has elapsed; the cached results are removed as part of a max cached queries exceeded purge, or a code based flush of the entire query cache.

```
<cffunction name="getData" access="public" output="false" returntype="string" hint="Returns a hash of the supplied string.">
    <cfargument name="Id" type="numeric" required="true">
    <cfargument name="ClearCache" type="boolean" default="false" required="false">

    <!--- Long cache the query since the values rarely change, but allow the cache to be cleared. --->
    <cfif Arguments.ClearCache EQ false>
        <cfset local.CachedWithin = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,10,0)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset local.CachedWithin = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,-1)>
    </cfif>

    <!--- Run the query --->
    <cfquery name="local.qryGetData" datasource="#Variables.DSN#" cachedwithin="#local.CachedWithin#">
        ...
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn local.qryGetData>
</cffunction>
```

You can then have a function that you run after an update to clear out the relevant cached queries.

```
<cffunction name="clearCache" access="public" output="false" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="Id" type="numeric" required="true">

    <cfset Variables.getData(Id=Arguments.Id,  ClearCache=true)>
    <cfset Variables.getSomethingElse(Id=Arguments.Id, ClearCache=true)>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Cool. That looks nice. Trying it out

Comment: The limit for cached queries is 10,000. This number is not that high be default and must be changed in the CF administrator. I'm not sure what it is in Railo. You'll definitely want to make sure that you have the number above the number of queries X the number of active sessions on the site.